# File selection within InnoSetup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal

I want the user to select a license file during the installation, how can I create this kind of dialog?  Can anyone show some sample code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a code example in the Inno Setup documentation (see "Pascal Scripting", "Support Functions Reference", "Dialog functions" - you can start [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm)):

```
var
  FileName: string;
begin
  // Set the initial filename
  FileName := '';
  if GetOpenFileName('', FileName, '', 
     'Text Documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files|*.*', 'txt') then
  begin
    // Successful; user clicked OK
    // Filename contains the selected filename
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for your contribution, that saved me some hours :)